# how to click webelement under overlay tag through selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, overlay, ui-automation

I have one webpage in which after login overlay screen has come. In that overlay screen I want to click on button which is not clickable. This overlay screen is not in different frame. Its in same page.

Please look into the below page structure and let me advise for same.

```
<overlay>
    <div class="full-screen" ng-show="showOverlay">
        <div class="dashboard-overlay"></div>
        <div class="welcome-dialog animated bounceIn">
            <div class="welcome-title">
                <p>Hi hello</p>
                <a class="mk-btn mk-btn-primary mk-btn-sm next-btn" ng-click="hideOverlay()">Next</a>
            </div>
```

And here what i simply use xpath to AUTOMATE this button. But it is not working
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//overlay/div/div/a")).click();`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that link has 3 `div` ancestors, while there are only 2 in your `XPath`. Try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//overlay/div/div/div/a")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@ng-click="hideOverlay()"]')).click();
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem. Thanks